# How do I verify publisher acknowledge behavior

Tags: go, rabbitmq, amqp

I am writing a go program with publisher confirms, and I want to verify the behavior when a message can be delivered/not be delivered to the broker.

I am doing this from an integration test that sets up a queue, and asks my system code to send to that queue name. Verifying the behavior for publisher ack is no problem, but I cannot provoke a situation that results in a publisher nack.

I try to send a message to a non-existing queue with the following piece of code:

```
connection, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://localhost")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer connection.Close()
channel, err := connection.Channel()
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = channel.Confirm(false)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
pubAck, pubNack := channel.NotifyConfirm(make(chan uint64, 1), make(chan uint64, 1))
fmt.Println("Publish to queue: ", queueName)
msg := amqp.Publishing{
    Body: []byte("Hello")}
err = channel.Publish("", queueName, true, true, msg)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
select {
case <-pubAck:
    fmt.Println("Ack")
case <-pubNack:
    fmt.Println("NAck")
}
```

The queue name is indeed a non existing queue, and executing `sudo rabbitmqctl list_queues` shows that the list of queues is empty.

But it still prints "Ack"

I have set both `mandatory` and `immediate` to true

> Publishings can be undeliverable when the mandatory flag is
>   true and no queue is bound that matches the routing key, or when the
>   immediate flag is true and no consumer on the matched queue is ready
>   to accept the delivery

Is my approach for sending to a non-existing queue a wrong approach, and is there another way I can send a message that will provoke a publisher nack?

Comment: if you want to get a confirmation from the server that the message was delivered to a queue (and eventually persisted in case of persistent messages), then you need to use publisher confirms.

Answer (score 1):

RabbitMQ will only return a `basic.nack` if

> an internal error occurs in the Erlang process responsible for a queue.

So, the `basic.ack`/`basic.nack` is only confirming if the RabbitMQ broker received the message, not if a "final" consumer did.  See the last sentence of "Negative Acknowledgement" on [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html) page.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that pretty much means that I cannot programatically provoke a publisher nack?

Comment: You might be able to write some plugin for RabbitMQ which when you publish to a certain virtual host, exchange, and/or routing key would die on purpose in such a way as to force a publisher.nack.  But yes, in general it would not be possible.